# Are node numbers in Advanced Forum stable or can they change or be reused?

Tags: nodes

We run Drupal as our CMS and use the [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module to provide a forum to users of our software. One issue in our bug tracker related to a discussion thread on said forum, so one of our devs included a link to that thread in the description of the issue.
The link had the form "https://www.example.com/en/node/1405".

When the time to verify the fix for the issue came, the (other) dev in charge found that the link pointed to a completely unrelated thread. We've searched, but couldn't find the right one and, at this point, we don't even know whether the original thread still exists.

The question is, whether it's possible that the node numbers of discussion threads have changed, somehow. I doubt it, but I don't know enough about the Advanced Forum module to be certain. What happens when a forum thread gets deleted, for instance. Does the node number become free for reuse, or will it be forever blocked?

It is just possible, that the link was incorrect from the beginning, but there's no way to make sure of that now.

Comment: It depends - check the `nid` column in the node table to see if it's auto-incremented, and compare that against the rules for auto-incrementing columns in your DBMS. Conventionally, the "next" ID is "currenthighest + 1", so deleted IDs won't be used

Comment: @Clive 
OK, I checked in the DB and the `nid` column has `auto_increment` set.
The RDBMS is MySQL, which AFAIK does things the way you described, i.e. it takes the largest value in the column and adds one.

From what I've read, there seems to be a way to explicitly set a different value in an `auto-increment` column, but it can't be smaller than the largest value already in there, to avoid collisions. So at best, one can generate a "gap" this way.

It seems that there's no way that node number could ever have pointed to a different thread...